# Goroutine started but not executed or partially executed even if using WaitGroup to synchronize

Tags: go, synchronization, channel, goroutine

I ran into a weird problem when using data received through channel from another goroutine to start multiple goroutines to reverse linked list simultaneously, which has troubled me for many days, I just want to split list into a couple of sublist without break link and then respectively start goroutine to reverse it, but I always get runtime error as below output shows when running code, I really don't know how to fix it after I tried many changes but still got the same error, can someone point out the problem or give me advice? any help you can give is welcome and appreciated, It would be nice if you can provide improved code, thanks in advance!

**UPDATE: the problem was caused by memory corruption due to data race, it has been solved by using read-write lock!**

Here is my code:

```
package main

import "sync"

type node struct {
    data int
    next *node
}

type LinkedList struct {
    head *node
    size int
}

type splitResult struct {
    beforeHead, head, tail *node
}

func splitList(head *node, sizoflst, sizofsublst int) <-chan *splitResult {
    nGoroutines := sizoflst / sizofsublst
    if sizoflst < sizofsublst {
        nGoroutines++
    } else {
        if (sizoflst % sizofsublst) >= 6 {
            nGoroutines++
        }
    }
    ch := make(chan *splitResult, nGoroutines)
    go func() {
        defer close(ch)
        var beforeHead *node
        tail := head
        ct := 0
        for i := 0; i < nGoroutines; i++ {
            for ct < sizofsublst-1 && tail.next != nil {
                tail = tail.next
                ct++
            }
            if i == nGoroutines-1 {
                testTail := tail
                for testTail.next != nil {
                    testTail = testTail.next
                }
                ch <- &splitResult{beforeHead, head, testTail}
                break
            }
            ch <- &splitResult{beforeHead, head, tail}
            beforeHead = tail
            head = tail.next
            tail = head
            ct = 0
        }
    }()
    return ch
}

func reverse(split *splitResult, ln **node, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    move := split.head
    prev := split.beforeHead
    if split.tail.next == nil {
        *ln = split.tail
    }
    for move != split.tail.next {
        temp := move.next
        move.next = prev
        prev = move
        move = temp
    }
}

func (ll *LinkedList) Reverse(sizofsublst int) {
    var lastNode *node
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    if ll.head == nil || ll.head.next == nil {
        return
    }
    splitCh := splitList(ll.head, ll.size, sizofsublst)
    for split := range splitCh {
        wg.Add(1)
        go reverse(split, &lastNode, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    ll.head = lastNode
}

func (ll *LinkedList) Insert(data int) {
    newNode := new(node)
    newNode.data = data
    newNode.next = ll.head
    ll.head = newNode
    ll.size++
}

func main() {
    ll := &LinkedList{}
    sli := []int{19, 30, 7, 23, 24, 0, 12, 28, 3, 11, 18, 1, 31, 14, 21, 2, 9, 16, 4, 26, 10, 25}
    for _, v := range sli {
        ll.Insert(v)
    }
    ll.Reverse(8)
}
```

output:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x8 pc=0x458db5]

goroutine 21 [running]:
main.reverse(0xc4200820a0, 0xc420096000, 0xc420098000)
        /home/user/go/src/local/stackoverflow/tmp.go:69 +0x75
created by main.(*LinkedList).Reverse
        /home/user/go/src/local/stackoverflow/tmp.go:85 +0x104
```

Comment: You've included a ton of code. Please simplify to an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is *two hundred forty lines* of source. That's an order of magnitude more than should be in an SO question. Perhaps you were looking for [codereview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself.*

Comment: Hello @Adrian, I am new to stackoverflow and sorry for violating some rules related with asking question, I just streamlined the code and rewrite question, can you take a look at it again? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is just assigning a value to Nil. Don't assign a Nil pointer in every place.

[Code Here](https://play.golang.org/p/VkG6JCYEC7j)